# editing wordpress html FTP connection

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Im working with total commander. I connected to ftp server of a website which uses wordpress theme. Im to edit some texts in the website but i fail to find a html in those files. Where is wordpress html located? I know its generated by PHP but i tried to find specific text/html in all files and failed to find it.

Comment: Maybe you should read a bit about [What is a CMS?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) and [How to get start with Wordpress?](https://codex.wordpress.org/Getting_Started_with_WordPress)

Answer (score -1):

index.html should be in the root folder, you better edit texts via wordpress editor, because pages are automatically generated with php. There are no separate html files for each page.

Comment: so i should download wordpress and edit it with it? Can i connect to sites FTP with wordpress? bcs site is already up.

Comment: go to your site <url>/wp-admin, enter username and password, and you will enter the admin panel

Comment: well but i only have ftp access. and loging/password to ftp and to wordpress arent the same.

Comment: Well then, it depends on which part of the template you want to edit.

Comment: so you should edit appropriate php files like header.php, footer.php etc

Comment: that was first thing i tried , but i could find there the html and texts im to edit